# How to write switch statement for a string type?

Tags: c#, winforms, switch-statement

I used a serial port to connect a device which returns to me ":GS#" string. After a long inspection, I am almost sure the problem is from 
switch condition, i.e., my program never enters cases and always goes to default. I printed the recieved string in a text box and it was
":GS#" ! I am confused. where is my mistake?

Here is my code:

```
char[] lxCMD = new char[8];
.
.
.

private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  serialPort.Read(lxCMD, 0, lxCMD.Length);
  this.Invoke(new EventHandler(UpdateVar));
        }

private void UpdateVar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string strRecieved = "Ack";
  if (lxCMD[0] != 0x6)
  {
    strRecieved = new string(lxCMD);
  }
  textBox1.AppendText(strRecieved);  // This line prints :GS# correctly!
  textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
  switch(strRecieved)
    {
      case ":GS#":
          serialPort.Write("20:08:18#");
          textBox1.AppendText("1:");  
          textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
              break;
       case "Ack":
          serialPort.Write("1");
          textBox1.AppendText("2:");
          textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
              break;
       default:
          textBox1.AppendText("Nothing");
              break;

            }

        }
```

Comment: Are there any control characters added to your string? Maybe you should sanitize it before switching.

Comment: Are there any spaces or nonprintable characters at the end of the string? Given your `char[]` is 8 characters long, the strings may also be that length.

Comment: There's no reason why that shouldn't work UNLESS you are not receiving exactly :GS#. Check things like string length for unprinted characters.

Comment: I checked it by Terminal v1.93b. The hex string is 3A 47 53 23 which exactly matches to ":GS#".

Comment: @Pana - Check the length of the string. .NET doesn't use null-terminating strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments your `char` array in which you save the read bytes is 8 characters long. So when you convert that array to a string it creates a string with the length of 8, you can check that by calling `strRecieved.Length` for example:

```
textBox1.AppendText(strRecieved);  // This line prints :GS# correctly!         
textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
Console.Out.WriteLine(strRecieved.Length); //or any other means of output - will output 8
```

This means there are some non printable characters in the string (null by ASCII table). And therefore the case doesn't match!

Since the `Read` method of your serial port returns the number of bytes read try using that to get the correct substring. For example (I Think this should work):

```
char[] lxCMD = new char[8];
var bytesRead = 0; 
.
.
.

private void serialPort_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
  bytesRead = serialPort.Read(lxCMD, 0, lxCMD.Length);
  this.Invoke(new EventHandler(UpdateVar));
        }

private void UpdateVar(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string strRecieved = "Ack";
  if (lxCMD[0] != 0x6)
  {
    strRecieved = new string(lxCMD);
    strRecieved = strRecieved.SubString(0, bytesRead)
  }
  textBox1.AppendText(strRecieved);  // This line prints :GS# correctly!
  textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
  switch(strRecieved)
    {
      case ":GS#":
          serialPort.Write("20:08:18#");
          textBox1.AppendText("1:");  
          textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
              break;
       case "Ack":
          serialPort.Write("1");
          textBox1.AppendText("2:");
          textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
              break;
       default:
          textBox1.AppendText("Nothing");
              break;

            }

        }
```

Comment: It works now! but sometimes the value of `bytesRead` is 1 and `strRecieved` is ":" and then `bytesRead = 3` and `strRecieved = GS#`. Why sometimes is there an interrupt? Is there some parameters to set for serial port to avoid having interrupt?

Answer (score 1):

change your string strRecieved initialization in the if statement to be:

```
strRecieved = new string(chars.TakeWhile(c => c != '\0').ToArray());
```

the issue is that the char array is holding multiple \0 characters at the end if the input is not length 8.

the following test demonstrate it:

```
[Test]
    public void stringConstructor_CharArrayWithSomeEmptyValues_StringWithoutEmptyValues()
    {
        var expected = "test";
        var chars = new char[expected.Length+42];
        chars[0] = expected[0];
        chars[1] = expected[1];
        chars[2] = expected[2];
        chars[3] = expected[3];
        var str = new string(chars.TakeWhile(c => c != '\0').ToArray());

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, str);
        str = new string(chars,0,chars.Length);
        Assert.AreNotEqual(expected, str);
    }
```